# binomial coefficient for very high numbers in c

Tags: c, math

So the task I have to solve is to calculate the binomial coefficient for 100>=n>k>=1 and then say how many solutions for n and k are over an under barrier of 123456789.
I have no problem in my formula of calculating the binomial coefficient but for high numbers n & k -> 100 the datatypes of c get to small to calculated this.

Do you have any suggestions how I can bypass this problem with overflowing the datatypes.
I thought about dividing by the under barrier straight away so the numbers don't get too big in the first place and I have to just check if the result is >=1 but i couldn't make it work.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be solving this wit brute force by calculating all C(n, k) blindly, but by working from the bottom up with Pascal's triangle. (Okay, that's typically rendered top down, but you know what I mean.) You can stop when you exceed your limit.

Comment: "I have no problem in my formula of calculating the binomial coefficient " -- Formulas may look [simple on paper](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130508-00/?p=4423), but they often don't lend themselves to direct implementation in code.

Comment: 123456789 is 0x75BCD15 in hex, which is well below 0x7FFFFFFF (the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer).  So you integer overflow shouldn't be a problem.  Still, you could use `uint64_t` for everything.

Comment: so maybe i missunderstand you but I need all the result above this limit that’s the problem that at somepoint it overflows

Comment: Well, C(100, 50) is 100,891,344,545,564,193,334,812,497,256. You will need an [arbitrary precision library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) for numbers of that size. (You say that you need to calculate the C(n, k) and say how many exceed the limit. To me, that sounds as if you only need to count them, but it's hard to be sure without seeing the original assignment.)

Answer (score 2):

Say your task is to determine how many binomial coefficients C(n, k) for 1 ≤ k < n ≤ 8 exceed a limit of m = 18. You can do this by using the recurrence C(n, k) = C(n − 1, k) + C(n − 1, k − 1) that can visualized in [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

```
                              1
                            1   1
                          1   2   1
                        1   3   3   1
                      1   4   6   4   1
                    1   5  10  10   5   1
                  1   6  15 (20) 15   6   1
                1   7 (21  35  35  21)  7   1
              1   8 (28  56  70  56  28)  8   1
```

Start at the top and work your way down. Up to n = 5, everything is below the limit of 18. On the next line, the 20 exceeds the limit. From now on, more and more coefficients are beyond 18.

The triangle is symmetric and strictly increasing in the first half of each row. You only need to find the first element that exceeds the limit on each line in order to know how many items to count.

You don't have to store the whole triangle. It is enough to keey the last and current line. Alternatively, you can use the algorithm detailed [in this article][ot] to work your way from left to right on each row. Since you just want to count the coefficients that exceed a limit and don't care about their values, the regular integer types should be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

First, you'll need a type that can handle the result. The larget number you need to handle is C(100,50) = 100,891,344,545,564,193,334,812,497,256. This number requires 97 bits of precision, so your normal data types won't do the trick. A [quad precision IEEE float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) would do the trick if your environment provides it. Otherwise, you'll need some form of high/arbitrary precision library.

Then, to keep the numbers within this size, you'll want cancel common terms in the numerator and the denominator. And you'll want to calculate the result using `( a / c ) * ( b / d ) * ...` instead of `( a * b * ... ) / ( c * d * ... )`.